# Set first fields open in a dynamic form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dynamic form where users can add data. By default i want to set the form in this way:
[image]

How you can see, the first pair of input is open when user opens the application.

I made this by changing this:

```js
const Demo = () => {
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log("Received values of form:", values);
  };
 
  return (
    <Form name="dynamic_form_nest_item" onFinish={onFinish} autoComplete="off">
      <Form.List name="users">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          console.log(fields);
          return (
            <div>
              {fields.map(field => (
                <Space
                  key={field.key}
                  style={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: 8 }}
                  align="start"
                >
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, "first"]}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "first"]}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing first name" }]}
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                  </Form.Item>
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, "last"]}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "last"]}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing last name" }]}
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="Last Name" />
                  </Form.Item>

                  <MinusCircleOutlined
                    onClick={() => {
                      remove(field.name);
                    }}
                  />
                </Space>
              ))}

              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  }}
                  block
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add field
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>

      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

to this:

```js
const Demo = () => {
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log("Received values of form:", values);
  };
  const firstDefaultOpen = {
    name: 0,
    key: 0,
    isListField: true,
    fieldKey: 0
  };
  return (
    <Form name="dynamic_form_nest_item" onFinish={onFinish} autoComplete="off">
      <Form.List name="users">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          console.log(fields);
          return (
            <div>
              {fields.concat(firstDefaultOpen).map(field => (
                <Space
                  key={field.key}
                  style={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: 8 }}
                  align="start"
                >
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, "first"]}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "first"]}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing first name" }]}
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                  </Form.Item>
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, "last"]}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "last"]}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing last name" }]}
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="Last Name" />
                  </Form.Item>

                  <MinusCircleOutlined
                    onClick={() => {
                      remove(field.name);
                    }}
                  />
                </Space>
              ))}

              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  }}
                  block
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add field
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>

      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

Issue: But appears a problem when i try to add another input, because writing on first  pair of inputs i can see the same text on the next inputs. Probably this is hapenening because of the same ids.
**Question**: How to set default open first pair of input as in the image using the code above?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-star-nu5ld?file=/index.js:235-2322
ps: i know that exists the next solution:

```css
  <Form initialValues={{ users: [""] }} name="dynamic_form_nest_item" onFinish={onFinish} autoComplete="off">
      <Form.List name="users">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          console.log(fields);
          return (
            <div>
              {fields.map(field => (
              ...
              ...
```

But i don't want this solution because i can't interact with `<Form/>` tag in my real application, so even this could be a solution, but i need another, like mine with `concat()` but of course to be workable.